# Entity Framework 4.3 data migrations: non-existing database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-migration, entity-framework-4.3

I want to handle such situation:

- I have an existing model (e.g. version 1.0);
- I've added several data migrations and run them one-by-one consequentially;
- for some reasons the existing database has been dropped.

I created the database from the scratch by using `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyContext>` which will produce the latest scheme already with empty `__MigrationHistory` table.

*While the next execution of website the data migrations error will occur.*

The one way I found how to handle this is manually filling the `__MigrationHistory` table with all data migrations metadata which looks like not very optimistic.

Is any other way to handle such situation (scheme comparing for e.g.)?